# Ruby- error: Failed to build gem native extension. gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having issues with installing ruby gems in VScode via wsl ubuntu.

Specifically, rest-client,  json, pry-byebug, and byebug,   at the moment.
I was able to install the ruval gem and pry gem with no issues.
I'm not sure if some are lacking gem dependencies, need to be upgraded, or the filepath needs to change somehow.

I noticed the Ubuntu wsl terminal file path is "/mnt/C". May have something to do with it?
I think C/ is just regular windows, and /mnt/C is Ubuntu's version of the same, to access the C/  windows file path.

I keep getting messages like the below in my terminal :

```
// ♥  gem install json
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in 
PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: /home/mjj4685mjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210404-8832-c0i3v3.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
current directory: /home/mjj4685mjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make DESTDIR\= clean
current directory: /home/mjj4685mjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make DESTDIR\=
compiling generator.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wrestrict'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
make: *** [Makefile:244: generator.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in /home/mjj4685mjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/json-2.5.1 for inspection.     
Results logged to /home/mjj4685mjj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/json-2.5.1/gem_make.out[21:58:57]  
// ♥ Sandbox (main)
```

Comment: You have two separate errors there. One if because an outdated `gcc` version (run `sudo apt-get install gcc`), the other error is unknown. You will need to post the contents of the `mkmf.log` log file which is referenced in the error message.

Comment: @Casper
There was no actual mkmf.log file in this particular folder for the 2.5.1 json gem (as there were in others that I found in the same main gems folder). Maybe it didn't download far enough to create a mkmf.log file.

Comment: It's better if you edit your question and add the log output there. It gets messy and hard to read from the comments.

Comment: What does `gcc --version` return?

Comment: @Casper , yeah that's pretty bad, I'll fix now. I found the solution! See edit in the above original post. There was no mkmf.log file with details for a coupleof failed gem installs. The only thing that was in that folder was the gem_make.out file listed in the error notes.

Comment: Good work. Now you can write an answer to your own question and then remember to accept it. So edit your question back to a question, then provide the answer below and accept it. That way you follow the proper StackOverflow protocol: questions are at the top, and answers are in the section below.

Comment: @Casper , thanks for the tip! I'll be sure to follow protocol going forward.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't a /mnt/c/  path issue  :

```
warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
```

The gems failed to compile and fully install because I had an outdated version of 'gcc' (Homebrew).:

```
compiling generator.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wmisleading-indentation'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wrestrict'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wimplicit-fallthrough=0'
make: *** [Makefile:244: generator.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

SOLUTION:

In terminal run: `brew outdated`   ...and check to see if 'gcc' or 'g++' has any out-of-date
features.

Then run:  `brew upgrade`

(Source: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ)

Once upgrade installation was complete I was able to install gems as normal and all my programs ran just fine.